# How do I consolidate this table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem that I will try to describe like this. I have a table in PostgreSQL like below
[(here's what I have).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqtDe.png)

Now I'm wrapping my head around how to "merge" or "consolidate" this table to make it look like this one on -> [Here's what I **want to** have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blx84.png)

Multiple rows are the result of having different ID or different value in any column after in general (but I don't need that information anymore, so I may get rid of it without any consequences).

Is there any function or any trick that might bring me desired result?

What I have tried:

```
select "name"
       , "array_agg" [1][1] as math_grade 
       , "array_agg" [2][2] as history_grade 
       , "array_agg" [3][3] as geography_grade 
from (select "name"
             , array_agg(array[math_grade,history_grade,geography_grade]) 
      from temp1234 
      group by "name") as abc
```

Here is a example table:

```
create table temp1234 (id int
                       , name varchar(50)
                       , math_grade int
                       , history_grade int
                       , geography_grade int)
```

And example data:

```
insert into temp1234 values (1, 'John Smith', 3, null, null)
insert into temp1234 values (2, 'John Smith', null, 4, null)
insert into temp1234 values (3, 'John Smith', null, null, 3)
```

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried anything when you say: "Now I'm wrapping my head around how to" ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use the "array_agg" function to merge all the dates into one field, and then pick them one by one using indices.

Comment: Can you show me the code you have tried ?

Comment: Could you please post the entire question, in plain text, in this topic? Images hosted somewhere else, will be deleted some day and leave this topic useless. And I can't copy any content from an image in my favourite psql tool either...

Comment: @VBoka Yes, sure:

select "name", "array_agg" [1][1] as math_grade , "array_agg" [2][2] as history_grade , "array_agg" [3][3] as geography_grade  from (select "name", array_agg(array[math_grade,history_grade,geography_grade]) from temp1234
group by "name") as abc  

FrankHeikens you mean those tables? Sure
Here is the example table
id "name" math_grade history_grade geography_grade
1 John Smith 3  
2 John Smith  4 
3 John Smith   3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want but I am sure that with more data you will find this query is not covering all you need ? Please do provide more data for more detailed help.

```
select min(id), name, max(math_grade), max(history_grade), max(geography_grade)
from temp1234
group by name
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=55b788a731051403e6a24d6dcdb5e61c)

Comment: Actually I figured this same exact solution out myself during our conversation. Still, a big thank you for just assuring me this is a valid and not the worst solution.

Comment: Hello @Kolczan, well it will guide you in right direction for some solutions. But, as I have said, for more complicated examples you will need other kind of solutions...

Comment: I never actually posted anything on SO, so let me ask you as you're clearly more experienced here... do people tend to put their original code in questions? Because what I did was translating my current problem to a simple one and so I wrote a temporary piece of code that I showed here.

Comment: Hi @Kolczan I would suggest this: when asking a question imagine you need to answer it and then ask yourself what info do you need to be able to answer it. You do not need to post original code or original data but you can create dummy code and dummy data that will present your problem. Hope this answers your question.